# SQL Update email colum with first name and last name

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

Add to the email colum, the firstname and last_name from an actor table. It has to have this format firstname.lastname@email.com
All with updates

**Edit**: (Copied OP's own comment)

```
UPDATE ACTOR
    SET EMAIL = (SELECT FIRST_NAME || '.' || LAST_NAME || '@SAKILLA.COM' FROM ACTOR
```

Comment: Please clearly explain your question with code what you have tried?.

Comment: UPDATE ACTOR
SET EMAIL = (SELECT FIRST_NAME || '.' || LAST_NAME || '@SAKILLA.COM'
            FROM ACTOR);

Comment: Hi MikeMikeMike! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Comment: Email column is in same table , or  in other table?

Answer (score 3):

Here is why your query doesn't work:

```
UPDATE ACTOR SET EMAIL = 
  (SELECT FIRST_NAME || '.' || LAST_NAME || '@SAKILLA.COM' FROM ACTOR);
```

You update all records of table ACTOR. For each record you set EMAIL to a value you determine with a subquery. The subquery however doesn't select *one* value, but many values, which you can easily see when executing the subquery alone. This does not work, because the query is iterated record for record and only one value can be assigned per record, naturally.

In order to have such thing working, you would have to relate the subquery to the main query. (And as you access the same table, you must give it an alias name, so the DBMS sees whether you are talking about a record in the main query or subquery.

```
UPDATE ACTOR MAIN SET EMAIL = 
(
  SELECT SUB.FIRST_NAME || '.' || SUB.LAST_NAME || '@SAKILLA.COM' 
  FROM ACTOR SUB
  WHERE SUB.ACTOR_ID = MAIN.ACTOR_ID
);
```

But as you already see from the other answers: Why use a subquery at all? When looking at a record in the main query, you already have all values needed to build the email address.

```
UPDATE ACTOR SET EMAIL = FIRST_NAME || '.' || LAST_NAME || '@SAKILLA.COM';
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what database you're using, but it is probably what you're looking for.

```
UPDATE actor SET email = CONCAT(CONCAT(firstname, '.'), CONCAT(lastname, '@email.com'));
```

Comment: Why would you use 3 concats? You can use this function once to concat how many values you'd like - concat(value1,value2,value3..)

Comment: @sagi: Oracle doesn't support more than 2 arguments in concat() and since I didn't know what DB OP is using atm, I gave universal solution. Using || operator is obviously a better solution in this case.

Comment: No dbms specified and you're suggesting a product specific solution, without telling us which dbms it is for...